# My application is not working after installing update of Android System WebView

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, android-webview, android-sqlite

There was a legacy cordova app which stored "data" in the browser local storage.
The new version of this app is a native app which tried to access this "data" by accessing the local storage database.

The code snippet which achieved this was :-

```
private void tryToGetHistory()
    {
        final WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);
    /* JavaScript must be enabled if you want it to work, obviously */

        browser.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        browser.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);

        ContextWrapper contextWrapper = new ContextWrapper(this);
        // Find the data directory
        File dataDir = new File(contextWrapper.getFilesDir().getParent());
        // Get the localStorage file
        File appWebViewFilesDir = new File(dataDir, "app_webview/Local Storage/file__0.localstorage");

        String TAG = "%Databases%";
        // Make sure it exists...
        if (appWebViewFilesDir.exists())
        {

            SQLiteDatabase database = null;
            Cursor cursor = null;
            boolean success = false;
            try
            {
                // Open the sqlite database
                database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(appWebViewFilesDir.getPath(), null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

                // Get all the values in the item table, obviously you can query specific values if you want
                cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT value FROM ItemTable", new String[]{});
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                while (!cursor.isAfterLast())
                {
                    // Our items are blobs
                    byte[] itemByteArray = cursor.getBlob(0);

                    // Decode the UTF-16 blob into a nice Java string...
                    String itemString = new String(itemByteArray, Charset.forName("UTF-16LE"));

                    // Just dump the values to the log
                    Log.d(TAG, "Item Value: " + itemString);
                    cursor.moveToNext();
                }
            } catch (IOError ex)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "IO Error on getting data from previous version", ex);
            } catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "SQLite Exception", ex);
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e(TAG, "Exception", ex);
            } finally
            {
                // Safely close out our database..
                if (cursor != null)
                {
                    cursor.close();
                }
                if (database != null)
                {
                    database.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Earlier I had Android System WebView version 39, the this code was working fine.
Recently I updated my Android System WebView to version 56.0.2924.87 and then after that the above code snippet has stopped working.

I am now getting the following error :-

> 03-26 12:43:42.369 8691-8691/com.schneider.zelionfctimer E/SQLiteLog:
>   (1) near "(": syntax error 03-26 12:43:42.369
>   8691-8691/com.schneider.zelionfctimer E/SQLiteLog: (11) database
>   corruption at line 100646 of [b3bb660af9] 03-26 12:43:42.369
>   8691-8691/com.schneider.zelionfctimer E/SQLiteLog: (11) malformed
>   database schema (MmapStatus) - near "(": syntax error 03-26
>   12:43:42.370 8691-8691/com.schneider.zelionfctimer E/%Databases%:
>   SQLite Execption
>                                                                           android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: malformed
>   database schema (MmapStatus) - near "(": syntax error (code 11): ,
>   while compiling: SELECT value FROM ItemTable
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>                                                                               at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
>                                                                               at
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
>                                                                               at MainActivity.tryToGetHistory(MainActivity.java:79)
>                                                                               at MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:20)
>                                                                               at MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
>                                                                               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
>                                                                               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Can you please suggest how should I edit the above code snippet so that my app can support this webview update? 
My goal is to be able to extract data stored in the browser's local storage. I aware that the data in browser's local storage is stored in an SQLiteDatabase. 
Please help me , this is very important to me.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

> SQLiteDatabaseCorruptException: malformed database schema (MmapStatus) - near "(": syntax error

This means that the SQLite library cannot read the database file. Either the database file actually is corrupt, or that web view uses a newer version of the SQLite library than you are currently using.
Check if you can open the database file with the [latest version of `sqlite3` from the tools package](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html).

Comment: Hello @CL, after downgrading the the android system webview I am again able to read all the data, hence I propose that the database is not corrupted. I also cannot upgrade the SQLite version which comes with android. Interestingly when I use the this library (SQLCiper)      https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/ , which has its own implementation of SQLiteDatabase methods (such as openDatabase, rawQuery etc.) all works fine. The only problm of using this library is it adds 7MB to apk size.The code in this library was a little too much to go through to know why it's working.